# What happen if the app is stay pause for 2 3 days

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I observe that when my app is in a pause state for 2 3 days without touching the app/tablet, the app is starting from the login screen (Login screen is root/Launcher Activity of app), what is happening that my app has auto-login features if login first time but some times I see that my app shows the login dead screen, hence I will have to login again.

Comment: That's bound to happen you can not do anything about it . Os clear non-visible processes time to time when needed . you have to save your Session in some persistence way . SharedPreference or database .

Comment: I have already saved some data to preferences

Comment: If you are saving it then how come your app has logged out ?

Comment: That's just how Android works - your app could be destroyed at any time in the background (and Activities can be killed on rotation), so you have to design it so it saves and restores its state. Assume the worst case, and handle that gracefully! Have a read of this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#ui-dismissal-system

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` or `Room Database` to save the state of the user login.

Saving variables on **App Runtime** must not be your main plan.

Please include your code if you already are using this.